# What are security risks of a domain user accounts with denied interactive logon?

Tags: passwords, windows, active-directory, domain, service-account

When I create domain user account with denied interactive logon, **what are real security risks when hacker gets the password?**

http://paulasitblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/deny-interactive-logon-for-service.html

> Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local
> Policies / User Rights Assignment
>
> Deny log on locally: {service accounts' security group}
>
> Deny log on through Terminal Services: {service accounts' security
> group}

The reason why I ask is this:

> Because, unless you have a decent automated password management
> solution in place, resetting passwords for service accounts can be a
> huge task with the potential to cause service disruption, by denying
> interactive logons to service accounts, it is possible to configure
> them with passwords which do not expire, whilst ensuring an acceptable
> degree of security.

---

More specifically:
**What can a hacker do with credentials of such a service account if he gains also physical access to the same LAN where one of DC servers resides.** Can he list records from the AD database like using this command?

```
dsquery user -name Vojt*
```

Comment: Depends a lot where the attacker is (Internet? Domain LAN/VPN but not domain joined? A low-privilege user on the same domain?) and what you expose to the relevant location (RPC endpoints? SSH server? Windows file shares?). There are lots of ways to interact with a Windows machine, with authentication, without technically performing an interactive login, although I'm not personally sure which APIs correspond to each log on "location".

Comment: @CBHacking thanks, edited the question to be more specific.